# Renaming some columns of a df using rows from another df (python; pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, rename

I have two .csv files that I am using pandas library to read as df's in python.

First files has just one column with 15 rows that include title names. Second file has 20 columns and I want to rename the first 5 with my own created names and the last 15 columns using the 15 rows of the first file.

I have already saved the first file as df1 in python. Please tell me how I can save the second file as df2 while renaming the columns (I am using the name = code to rename the first 5 rows but I do not know how to incorporate a line of code that will rename the last 15 columns using df1)

I have two .csv files that I am using pandas library to read as df's in python.

First files has just one column with 15 rows that include title names. Second file has 20 columns and I want to rename the first 5 with my own created names and the last 15 columns using the 15 rows of the first file.

I have already saved the first file as df1 in python. Please tell me how I can save the second file as df2 while renaming the columns (I am using the name = code to rename the first 5 rows but I do not know how to incorporate a line of code that will rename the last 15 columns using df1)

Answer (score 1):

what you can do here is make variables for both dataframes, ie, df1 and df2, then use a list like this:

```py
Cols = ['name1','name2'.....,'name5'] + df1['colum_name'].tolist()
```

column name in the above sentence is the column containing the names of columns you want.

Then afterwards:

```py
df2 = pd.read_csv('file_path', names=Cols, header=None)
```